# Slick: combine actions with a Seq of DBIOAction

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.5

I have the (working) following code:

```
val actions = (for {
  _ <- slickUsers.insertOrUpdate(dbUser)
  loginInfo <- loginInfoAction
  _ <- slickUserLoginInfos += DBUserLoginInfo(dbUser.userID, loginInfo.id.get)
} yield ()).transactionally
```

with loginInfoAction being a DBIOAction. I would like to change loginInfoActions to a Seq of DBIOAction and for each of them, execute the same DBUserLoginInfo action afterwards.

I tried this stupidly:

```
val actions = (for {
  _ <- slickUsers.insertOrUpdate(dbUser)
  loginInfoAction <- loginInfoActions
  loginInfo <- loginInfoAction
  _ <- slickUserLoginInfos += DBUserLoginInfo(dbUser.userID, loginInfo.id.get)
} yield ()).transactionally
```

But it does not work as expected (I would have though loginInfoAction would iterate over the Seq of DBIOAction). I am a newbie in Slick so do not hesitate to point me to the documentation if I missed anything !

Comment: Please check the answer I have posted a new answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**DBIO.sequence**

Use `DBIO.sequence` to convert `List[DBIO[_]]` to `DBIO[List[_]]` and use for-comprehension.

`DBIO.sequence` will convert the sequence of DBIO's into `DBIO[Seq[_]]`.

For example let say we have a function `getUser`

```
def getUser(userId: Long): DBIO[User]

def getAllUsers(userIds: List[Long]): DB[List[User]] = {
  DBIO.sequence(userIds.map(getUser))
}
```

`DBIO.Sequence` converts `List[DBIO[_]]` to `DBIO[List[_]]`

Now your code becomes

```
val actions = (for {
  _ <- slickUsers.insertOrUpdate(dbUser)
  loginInfoActionList <- DBIO.sequence(loginInfoActions)
  _ <- DBIO.sequence { loginInfoActionList.map { loginInfo =>
           slickUserLoginInfos += DBUserLoginInfo(dbUser.userID, loginInfo.id.get) }
      }
} yield ()).transactionally
```

Comment: I am migrating a significant project to slick so I cannot be 100% sure, but it seems to compile at least !

Comment: I forgot to come back and say it, but it worked fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Still relevant to Slick 3.3.0, saved my day (or night) +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [slick-cats](https://github.com/RMSone/slick-cats) you should be able to write it like this:

```
import com.rms.miu.slickcats.DBIOInstances._

loginInfoActionList.traverse { loginInfo =>
       slickUserLoginInfos += DBUserLoginInfo(dbUser.userID, loginInfo.id.get)
}
```

Which is IMHO a bit easier on the eyes.